# Docker-machine instance is not talking to outside world ( i.e Internet )

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-machine

I was trying to connect to **AWS** instance using **docker-machine** Connection is done but it is giving error as

> Error getting SSH command to check if the daemon is up: Something went wrong running an SSH command!

I also ssh'd into the instance and I also tried **sudo apt-get update** it was giving the error

> Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/wily-backports/Release.gpg  Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com

It looks like the instance is not talking to the outside world ( i.e Internet)
So Can anyone help me to resolve this issue , Thanks

Comment: By any chance it is using VPC with no internet gateway attached?

Comment: Thanks for the reply , The VPC has the internet gateway attached .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even I had this similar issue, following these procedure resolved the issue and the instance was able to communicate with the outside world.

1. ssh into the particular instance , modify the file `/etc/resolv.conf`
2. within the file change the value `nameserver to 169.254.169.253`

this should work.

Comment: Worked for me. I had a same issue.

Comment: Thanks Pavan 
I just tried it and it looks like it is connecting to internet , Thanks for saving my valuable time .